# How i can install samba to unix server?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, installation, samba

How i can install samba to unix server ? .... for example i can install `openssh-client` in linux by the following command :-
`apt-get install openssh-client` 
how i can install samba in unix .... by command ??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install samba with apt-get

`sudo apt-get install samba smbfs`

EDIT

Solaris 9 may already have samba installed  to check run

```
pkginfo | grep samba
```

if it is installed you should see that the following packages are installed

```
system SUNWsmbac samba - A Windows SMB/CIFS fileserver for UNIX (client)
system SUNWsmbar samba - A Windows SMB/CIFS fileserver for UNIX (Root)
system SUNWsmbau samba - A Windows SMB/CIFS fileserver for UNIX (Usr)
```

if the packages are not installed then you will need to locate your original SUN installation media. To install the SAMBA packages above.

Mount the relevant disk in your CD drive then

```
cd /cdrom/cdrom0/Solaris_9/Product

pkgadd -d . SUNWsmbac 
pkgadd -d . SUNWsmbar
pkgadd -d . SUNWsmbau
```

I don't think that the bits of samba that you want (`smbmount`) are installed by default on Solaris though.

Comment: this in linux but how i can do it in unix please :)

Comment: Which variant of unix ?

Comment: Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.9       Generic May 2002

Comment: Why do you accept an answer that doesn't actually answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

solaris has installed samba
in hp-ux swinstall -s /path/to/depot/PKGNAME.depot

Comment: i have Sun Microsystems Inc. SunOS 5.9 Generic May 2002

Comment: then you already have samba :)